# Find similarities in tables

Tags: sql, database, similarity

I have a table with thousands of records:

```
+-----+-------+------+----------+
| id  | group | code |  label   |
+-----+-------+------+----------+
| 1   | abc   | 345  | myLabel1 |
| 2   | abc   | 345  | myLabel4 |
| 3   | def   | 987  | myLabel2 |
| 4   | def   | 345  | myLabel4 |
| 5   | def   | 987  | myLabel2 |
| 6   | def   | 231  | myLabel1 |
| 7   | def   | 231  | myLabel9 |
| 8   | abc   | 345  | myLabel3 |
| 9   | def   | 987  | myLabel2 |
| 10  | def   | 345  | myLabel1 |
| ... | ...   | ...  | ...      |
+-----+-------+------+----------+
```

In this table some entries are similar to each other.

For example 1,2 and 8: `group` is "abc" and `code` is "345".
Another example are entries 3, 5 and 9: `group` is "def", `code` is "987" and `label` is "myLabel2".

Formally one could say:

```
IF group = "abc", THEN code = "345"
IF group = "def" AND code = "987", THEN label = "myLabel2 "
```

I want to run a program over my tables which finds those similarities.

**PS:** This table is just an example. It actually has more than 20 columns with different names.

Comment: You are looking for association rules.  Although you *can* do this in SQL, I might first suggest that you use a tool that directly supports them.

Comment: Actually the language or the format is unimportant. I can export and convert the tables in any of them.  
Could you please suggest me a free (and simple) tool?

Comment: You can try the Apache Lucene. But it is far from simple. You wil have to study it and to chose appropriate methods to do your similarity search: https://lucene.apache.org/core/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you duplicate rows in table with number of time occurrence

```
SELECT      [group], [code] , COUNT(1) as CNT
FROM        YourTableName
GROUP BY    [group], [code] 
HAVING      COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY CNT;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the first as:

```
select group, min(code) as implied_code
from records 
group by group
having count(distinct code) = 1;
```

And the second as:

```
select group, code, min(label) as implied_label
from records 
group by group, code
having count(distinct label) = 1;
```

Note:  `group` is a really bad name for a column because it is a SQL reserved word.

Comment: My provided table is just an example. It actually has more than 20 columns with different names.

Comment: @user1170330 . . . You can do association rules in SQL.  This is one of the reasons why I wrote "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel".  I don't generally use Stack Overflow as a forum to mention my books, but does specifically devote a chapter to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to only return lines which have similarities:

```
SELECT group, code, [column3], [column4], ..., [column20]
FROM table 
GROUP BY group, code, [column3], [column4], ..., [column20]
HAVING count(1) > 1
```

You have to replace [columnX] by the column name you want to check similarities.

Comment: In this case I'm missing "def   987", which occurs 3 times.

Comment: Edit : If you have to check similarities on other columns you have to add them in the group by condition.